# Maximum file size supported by a file representation of a node?

Tags: file, unix, operating-system, filesystems, inode

[image]

For a I feel like it would be 63504 Bytes because the file size would be (496/4)*512 + 16 Bytes.. But I cant seem to get that in the requested format, which leads me to believe that I attempted it wrong.

For pt b I have no Idea how to approach it.. Any help/hints would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum file size given a particular inode structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742163/maximum-file-size-given-a-particular-inode-structure)

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service (or exam answering service). You're expected to show your code, along with relevant sample inputs, expected outputs, actual error msgs as well as your comments about where you are stuck. Please show your best effort to solve your **programming problem** (use the {} tool at the top left of the edit box to format code/data/output/errMsgs correctly), and people may be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: General computing questions, not directly related to programming, are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Examination questions and "do this work for me" kind of questions are not welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part [a]**

```
Starting with 

              Extent size 1 ==> File size will be 2^0 * 512 bytes 

              Extent size 2 ==>File size will be  2^1 * 512 bytes

              Extent size 3 ==>File size will be  2^2 * 512 bytes

              ......

              Extent size 12 ==>File size will be  2^11 * 512 bytes

              Extent size x ==>File size will be  2^(x-1) * 512 bytes
```

**Part [b]**

```
Considering 512 bytes as block size,

Number of disk accesses required for getting 1,00,000 byte will be,

100000/512  = 196
```

I hope it does make sense to you....